# How can i disable iTunes autoplay when bluetooth device is connected?

Tags: itunes, audio, sleep-wake, bluetooth

I don't know exactly when it began but for few months i have problem with bluetooth speakers. When they connected to mac iTunes starts to play music from it's playlist. How can i disable this function?

Also when my mac is in sleep mode and bluetooth speakers are connected, mac suddenly wakes up and start to play music from iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue on Mac. Here is the tutorials that works fine on my rMBP with OSX 10.11:

1) Open a Terminal Window

2) Rename iTunes.app to MyiTunes.app

3) Create a DoNothing.app using the AppleScript Editor

4) Copy the DoNothing.app to the Applications folder

5) Connect a bluetooth device to get the "Where is iTunes?" window prompt and Select DoNothing.app as what to auto-launch instead of iTunes 6) Closing thoughts about updates etc.

Resource: https://discussions.apple.com/message/25425864#message25425864

Comment: This no longer works on newer versions of MacOS (i.e. 10.13) with System Integrity Protection enabled

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Catalina (10.15.7) that didn't require renaming iTunes or anything else like that:

```
launchctl stop com.apple.rcd
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist
```

Keep in mind that this will disable the Remote Control Daemon (rcd). I have not found anything of consequence that relies on this, but this will prevent those events from firing.

Comment: Very interesting direction - seems to be a bit of an overkill since 'rcd' (is it documented anywhere) may be responsible for more than ,music autoplay. I bet it has some configuration somewhere (defaults read com.apple.rcd yields nothing)  that may be explored, and maybe there's a specific entry on audio autoplay...